# How to unit test a react component that uses inheritance instead of composition using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-router, enzyme

I have a component that extends a generic component (custom react component). How do I unit-test using enzyme's mount? Here's the code:

Container.js

```
import React from 'react';
import request from 'API/request';

export default class Container extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.isDataStale()) {
      return this.populateData();
    }
  }

  populateData() {
    const url = this.getUrl();
    const params = this.getParams();

return request(this.props.dispatch, {
  url,
  params,
  method: 'GET'
})
  .then(response => {
    this.dispatchData(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.dispatchError(error);
  });


}
render() {
    if (this.getData() && !this.isDataStale()) {
      return this.renderChildren();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  getError() {}
  getParams() {}
  isDataStale() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's the functional component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import CustomPage from 'Client/customPage';
import Container from 'Client/container';
import TestPanel from 'Client/testPanel/TestPanel';
import Greeting from 'Client/greeting';
import Button from '../Button';

export class Test extends Container {
  constructor({ match }) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      match: match,
      id: match.params.id,
      location: ''
    };
  }

  isDataStale() {
    return (
      this.props.data.id !== this.props.match.params.id
    );
  }

  getData() {
    return this.props.data.values;
  }

  dispatchData(data) {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'DATA_FOUND',
      data: data,
      id: this.state.id
    });
  }

  dispatchError(error) {
    this.props.dispatch({ type: 'CUSTOM_ERROR', data: error });
  }

  showDetails(url) {
    this.props.history.push(url);
  }

  renderChildren() {
    const match = this.state.match;
    const testUrl = `/test/values/${this.state.id}`;
    const verifyUrl = `${testUrl}/verify`;

    return (
      <div className="test-plan">
        <Route path={verifyUrl} render={() => (
          <Greeting show={true} />
        )} />
        <TestPanel
          data={this.props.data}
          id={this.props.match.params.id}
        />
        <Route exact path={testUrl} render={() => (
          <CustomPage id={this.state.id} />
        )} />
        <Route path={verifyUrl} render={() => (
          <div className="next-button" ><Button label = {' NEXT '} onButtonClick = { this.showDetails.bind(this, loanUrl) } /> </div>
        )} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.data
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Test));
```

How do I test this Test (functional) component using Enzyme? Am not sure how this mock works since the render method is inside the container which in turn invokes the renderChildren method in our functional component. Lot of functional components extends this container so we can't change this to composition pattern as of now.

Here's the test case (Not working)

```
import jsdomWindow from '../../test.setup';
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Test } from 'Client/containers/test';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Enzyme, {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as api from 'API/request';
import { populateData, isDataStale } from '../../../../src/client/app/container';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
const sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();

describe('<Test />',() => {
  beforeEach(function() {
    sandbox.stub(api, 'default').returns(Promise.resolve({data: { saySomething: 'Yay Tests!'}}));
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  const match = {
    params: {
      id: 100
    }
  };
  const testState = {
    data : {
      test: {
        id:'100',
        email:'someone@something.com',
        first_name:'John',
        home_phone:'325-555-6564',
        last_name:'Doe'
      }
    }
  };
  const wrapper = mount(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={createStore(state => state, { data: testState.data })}>
        <Test data={testState.data} dispatch={ sinon.spy() }
          match={match} />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  jest.mock('../../../../src/client/app/container', () => ({
    populateData: jest.fn(),
    isDataStale: jest.fn(),
    getError: jest.fn(),
    getParams: jest.fn(),

  }));

  it('should render', () => {
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
    populateData.mockReturnValueOnce({});
    isDataStale.mockReturnValueOnce(false);
    const greetingContainer = wrapper.find('.greeting-container').find('.quick-info').find('.quick-info-heading');
    expect(greetingContainer.text()).toContain('PROPER RESPONSE');
  });

  // it('should render greeting component by default', () => {
  //   expect(wrapper.find('div.greeting-container')).toBeDefined();
  //   expect(wrapper.find('div.info-container')).toBeDefined();
  //   expect(wrapper.find('div.next-button')).toBeDefined();
  // });

  // it('should not render greeting and next-button components on clicking next', () => {
  //   console.log(`Test**** ${JSON.stringify(wrapper.find('div.plan'))}`);
  // });
});
```

Could anyone help me to unit test this using mount method of enzyme. Don't want to use shallow here as i have to test nested components' properties.

Thank you.

Comment: If you mock out `request` and all the other props correctly it should be pretty straight forward. You mount `Test`, change it's props or state, and make assertions about spies having been called.

Comment: I mocked the component. But, it doesn't work. I have updated the test file as well. Please have a look.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Some remarks: I wouldn't test `BrowserRouter` and `Provider` if all you care about is the `Test` component. This makes your test setup unnecessarily complicated. Why do you need both sinon and jest mocking? Jest should be enough here, it restores automatically when the test is over.

Comment: I agree with @timotgl. You are already importing the non-connected component with `import { Test } from "blah/blah";` Why are you mocking the provider as opposed to just jamming in your props to the bare component? `mount(<Test {...props} />);` should do the job.